# WPF ListBox Trigger not working for IsFocused Property

Tags: wpf, triggers, listbox, focus

I want to style my `ListBox` and display a `Border` around it.  I want to hide this `Border` when `ListBox` gets focus:

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="border" Value="Collapsed"/>
</Trigger>
```

Same thing I'm using in `TextBox` also and it is working properly.
Why is this `Trigger` not working for `ListBox`?

**Edit:**

I am having this `Style` for my `ListBox`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ListBox}">
    <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Bd" CornerRadius="5"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="1">
        <Grid>
            <local:ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </local:ScrollViewer>
            <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="Red" x:Name="border">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Message}" FontFamily="Courier New" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="border" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more context? Can you show the style definition, how you are applying the style to the list box and the text box?

Comment: I have updated my code question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ListBox IsFocused not updating because focus does not goes to list box but it goes to area covered by listbox means the ItemsPresenter which contains ListBoxItems. I have got a workaround to this problem.
In MouseDown event handler of the ListBox, I call Focus() method. It sets the IsFocused property to true and make my trigger working.

Answer (score 5):

I was also having trouble getting your example to work properly. I've concluded that if you click on a `ListBoxItem`, the IsFocused property is going to be `False` for the `ListBox`, because it's really the `ListBoxItem` that has the focus. You'll see the commented XAML style below trying to achieve your desired effect, which didn't work.

I would imagine that the commented XAML **would** work if you clicked somewhere within the `ListBox` where there were no items (i.e. non-`ListBoxItem` white-space inside the `ListBox`). **Edit:** *Just tried this, doesn't work either for some reason.*

What did work, though, was creating a style for all `ListBoxItem` objects within the `ListBox`. That style basically has `EventSetters` that sets the `BorderBrush` property of MyListBox appropriately when fired.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderThickness="2">
    <!--<ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>-->
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="ListBoxItem_GotFocus"/>
            <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="ListBoxItem_LostFocus"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void ListBoxItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MyListBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
}

private void ListBoxItem_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MyListBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;
}
```

Hope this helped a little!

**EDIT:**
I wasn't satisfied with my original answer (above), because I like doing things declaratively when I code in WPF (no code-behind). I came up with a solution that uses simple color animations that triggers off of the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` routed events.

Here it is:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderThickness="2" Height="200">
        <ListBox.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
        </ListBox.BorderBrush>
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeBlack">
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" 
                                        To="Black" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeRed">
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" 
                                        To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeRed}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeBlack}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Happy coding!

**EDIT 2:**
I looked at your updated code, and saw what you were trying to do (I think). I found this neat-o animation at [Lester's WPF Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2006/08/31/Collapsing-animation-in-WPF.aspx). You can try putting this in your `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` collection:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBox.GotFocus">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBox.LostFocus">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Comment: i have posted my ControlTemplate which i am using inside my Style for ListBox, can you please tell me what is the problem with my listbox?

Comment: Please see my "Edit 2" section of my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: this is not working for me, How can i get IsFocused property working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works.

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.GotFocus">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="Orange" Duration="0:0:0.250"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.LostFocus">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.250"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```