# Style Error In WPF ListView

Tags: wpf

I want to change the border color of ListView when it's got focused. I use This style

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF9D9B9B" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter> 
</Style>
```

Here is the code for my ListView

```
<ListView  Margin="49,91,61,148" Grid.Column="1">
  <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"/>
       </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But after I apply this style, the ListView was totally disappeared in run time. What was happened there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's the `<ControlTemplate>`  Could you simply declare your style without it?

```
  <Style TargetType="ListView">
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Lime" /><!--bright color for empahsis only-->
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

This works without issue in a test project/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1790712/637953). Its about IsFocused property for ListBox but the same idea with ListView.

Comment: But why my ListView was disappeared